# Value range for $a$ when $\enspace 0\leq (e^x-1)\frac{1-(1-x)^a}{x}-x<1\enspace$ with $\enspace 0\leq x\leq 1$ .

Tags: real-analysis

It's given: $\enspace 0\leq x\leq 1\enspace $ and $\enspace a\geq 1$

The claim is, that

$$0\leq (e^x-1)\frac{1-(1-x)^a}{x}-x<1$$

is true.

Numerical tests confirm this, but I don't know how to prove it.

---

EDIT (now I know, thanks to *Kelenner* for the help):

With $\enspace a\ge 1\enspace$ it's

$\displaystyle \min(e^x-1-x)\leq\min((e^x-1)\frac{1-(1-x)^a}{x}-x)\leq (e^x-1)\frac{1-(1-x)^a}{x}-x\leq$

$\displaystyle \leq \max((e^x-1)\frac{1-(1-x)^a}{x}-x)<\max(\frac{e^x-1}{x}-x)$

With the help of the derivations of the functions one gets

$\displaystyle\min(e^x-1-x)=(e^x-1-x)|_{x=0}=0\enspace$ and

$\displaystyle\max(\frac{e^x-1}{x}-x)=(\frac{e^x-1}{x}-x)|_{x=0}=1$

which proofs the claim.

Comment: $$a \in \{t \in \mathbb{R} | t \geq 1 \}$$ Why would you do this to yourself? Who hurt you?

Comment: @D.Beec : Better now ? :-) ... Any idea ?

Comment: For $x\in ]0,1]$ and $a\geq 1$, you have $x\leq 1-(1-x)^a\leq 1$. So it is sufficient to show that $x\leq \exp(x)-1$ and $\exp(x)-1\leq x+x^2$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Kelenner: Thanks for the hint!